# Calculating overall survival probability for being a part of a group in Cox regression

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, hazard

I have created a mixed-effects Cox regression in r:

This can be created in coxph:

```
library(survival)
kidney <-  data.frame(kidney)

coxph.me <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + frailty(disease), 
                  data = kidney,
                  x = TRUE)
```

Or coxme:

```
library(coxme)

coxme <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + (1|LA), 
                  data = kidney)
```

`summary(coxph.me)` produces a hazard ratio (`exp(coef)`) of 0.309 for sex2.

I want to convert this into a survival probability for sex1 and sex2 but I am unsure how.

This is a similar principle to what is outlined in the University of Cambridge's [REALRISK calculator](https://realrisklight.wintoncentre.uk/).

My current approach has been to average the outputs of predictSurvProb, but these do not pass the test when converted back to hazard ratios or calculating the risk from reference group (sex1) hazard:

```
library(pec)

surv_prob_fn <- function(model, variable, factor, reference, HR){
  
  
  #use predictSurvProb to predict surv prob
  # references
  filtered_kidney <- kidney %>%
    filter({{variable}} == reference)
  
 filtered_kidney <- subset(filtered_kidney, select = c(age, sex, disease))
  

  overall_surv_ref <- predictSurvProb(model, newdata = filtered_kidney, times = c(100))


  # factor
  filtered_kidney <- kidney %>%
    filter({{variable}} == factor)

  filtered_kidney <- subset(filtered_kidney, select = c(age, sex, disease))
  
  overall_surv_fact <- predictSurvProb(model, newdata = filtered_kidney, times = c(100))


  # risk
  sp_ref = round(mean(overall_surv_ref),3)
  r_ref = 1 - sp_ref
  sp_fact = round(mean(overall_surv_fact),3)
  r_fact = 1 - sp_fact
  
  HR = as.numeric(HR)

  # checks
  HR_logic <- ifelse(round(log(sp_ref)*HR,3) == round(log(sp_fact,3)), 'True', 'False')
  p_logic <- ifelse(round(r_fact,3) == round(1-(1-r_ref)^HR,3), 'True', 'False')

  print(paste0('Reference Survival Probability: ', sp_ref))
  print(paste0('Factor Survival Probability: ', sp_fact))
  print(paste0('Hazard Ratio logic is ', HR_logic))
  print(paste0('Real Risk logic is ', p_logic))

  
  
}


surv_prob_fn(coxph.me, sex, '1', '2', 0.309)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unrealistic to expect the model-predicted survival probability for a group to match the results of your calculations based on the individuals.

The nonlinearities in fitting Cox models make that difficult even when you have a model without frailty terms or random effects. The survival probability prediction at the average age of your group need not be the same as the average survival of your group. The problems are discussed in Chapter 10 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842).

The predicted survival probability at time $t$ in a Cox model can be related to the estimated baseline cumulative hazard function $\hat\Lambda_0$, the vector of covariate values $X$ and the corresponding vector of Cox coefficient estimates $\hat\beta$ by:

$$S(t) = \exp(-e^{X'\hat\beta} \hat\Lambda_0(t))= \exp(-\text{HR } \hat\Lambda_0(t)),$$

where $\text{HR}$ is the hazard ratio (relative to baseline) corresponding to the covariate values. Although the instantaneous hazard is proportional to $\text{HR}$, the survival probability at any time is *exponentially* related to $\text{HR}$.

That's even more of a problem with frailty or random-effect terms. Predictions from such models are provided for a random-effect term of 0, so predictions and simple averages are even less likely to match (and then, only by chance).

You could avoid that last problem while taking correlations among observations into account by using a `cluster()` term instead of a `frailty()` or random-effect term. That gives a marginal model for the population rather than a model conditional upon an individual's frailty/random-effect value.

What's probably best is to show the survival curve over time at representative values for the covariates that aren't of primary interest. If you need something more elaborate, consult Chapter 10 of Therneau and Grambsch.